# VS 2015 compiler throwing error on struct

Tags: c#, struct

I'm running VS 2015 v14.0.25431.01 Update 3. When I try to compile the following code, I get the error "CS1513  } expected" on line 1 in the module in question. What's wrong?

```
<!-- Build a structure of States. -->
@using System.Collections;
@{ 
    struct structState
    {
        private string s_abbrev;
        public string abbrev
        {
            get
            {
                return s_abbrev;
            }
            set
            {
                s_abbrev = value;
            }
        }

        private string s_name;
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return s_name;
            }
            set
            {
                s_name = name;
            }
        }

        public structState(string a_abbrev, string a_name)
        {
            s_abbrev = a_abbrev;
            s_name = a_name;
        }
    }

    structState[] dumState = new structState[50];

}
```

Comment: Is that defined in a razor view?

Comment: A type like that shouldn't be a struct, it should be a class, since it's mutable.  It should also almost certainly be defined in its own .cs file, rather than inline in markup.

Comment: Yes, Andez it is defined in a razor view.

Answer (score 0):

Please define your structure inside `@functions` directive to fix the issue.

```
@{
    structState[] dumState = new structState[50];
}


@functions
{

    struct structState
    {
        private string s_abbrev;
        public string abbrev
        {
            get
            {
                return s_abbrev;
            }
            set
            {
                s_abbrev = value;
            }
        }

        private string s_name;
        public string name
        {
            get
            {
                return s_name;
            }
            set
            {
                s_name = name;
            }
        }

        public structState(string a_abbrev, string a_name)
        {
            s_abbrev = a_abbrev;
            s_name = a_name;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: That worked. Now when I try to create an array of the struct, it doesn't recognize the array name I define (the array name doesn't appear under Intellisense):     structState[] arrayState = new structState[50];

Comment: The IntelliSense issue is not happening for me on VS 2017. Remember that you cannot use this struct outside of the view you defined it in. If you want to share you must define it in the code (not in the view).

Comment: Never mind. I needed to set my struct to public - DOH! It's working now. Txs for the help!